# Migrating multiple hierarchical TFVC branches into TFS-GIT

Tags: version-control, tfvc, git-tfs

We want to migrate existing TFVC to TFS-GIT using existing team project with multiple branches. I found some tutorials that I could follow to migrate every branches. But their is something that makes me wonder if we can maintain or re-arrange our TFVC branch hierarchy in TFS-GIT?

Let us say we have branch hierarchy like this:

```
   Prod <---> Pre-Prod <---> TEST <----> DEV
```

And during the migration process into TFS-GIT, we want to re-arrange the branch hierarchy depend on our discretion. Like for example I want to have something like this in TFS-GIT:

```
   Prod <---> Pre-Prod <---> DEV <----> TEST   // Just an illustration of what I want.
```

Is someone here have achieved what we want to do? Can you point me out into the right direction?

Technically, we can migrate Prod branch as master branch and branch out Pre-prod. But for the existing TFVC Dev we have **a lot** on-going work and change-sets.

**Disclaimer :** This is my first to do it and I made a research but most of the tutorial I found is only one branch can be migrated. But how about the branch hierarchy? Apology for a naive question.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating all branches from TFVC to git using git-tfs

https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md#fetch-all-the-history-for-all-branches

Ps: please fix your question because what you call git-tfs is in fact TFS-git (git-tfs is the tool https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will look into it. I also edit my question base on you suggestion.